# peer channel create yeilds: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- backing Kafka cluster has not completed booting; try again later

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a hyperledger Fabric 1.4 Cluster running with Kafka ordering.  3 peers, 3 orderers, 4 kafka brokers, 3 zookeepers.  all seem to be running fine in Kubernetes.  But when i run a peer channel create command i get the error...

```
[channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- backing Kafka cluster has not completed booting; try again later
```

Comment: There is something wrong in your kafka environment, can you see kafka logs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by giving more RAM to the cpu, or you can try to wait longer

Comment: how did you figure out that its was less amount of RM which was causing this issue? Did you see any relevant logs?

Comment: yea, for the first few times, it said```backing Kafka cluster has not completed booting; try again later```, then when I try to put the command again, ```it said run out of memory```. When I give it 2 gb of ram, it runs perfectly.

Comment: ive got 16gb of ram

Comment: Okay, I don't know about that. in my case, I am running linux 18.0 from vagrant in my Mac. After I changed the settings for linux environment to 2 gb of ram, it ran perfectly.